# How do I drop outliers across axis 1 in python's Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datframe of so many rows and 2000 columns of samples for each row.  Each row consists of a product and each column consists of one point in a distribution of possible sales.

How do I drop all points of each distribution (across columns) outside of the 2.5% and 97.5% of the rows?  I'd like to take the mean across `axis=1` without having the outliers in the data.  I need to do this for each product (row).

Here is some random data

```
import numpy
import pandas 

cols = np.random.rand(10, 2000)
df = pd.DataFrame(cols)
```

I tried:

df.quantile([.025,.975],axis=1) but that puts the products as column and just the 2.5% and 97.5% values.

Comment: the df is the sample.  each row represents product.  each col represents one value of the distribution.

Comment: Did the solution below work out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.where` and take only non-outlier columns into consideration:

```
def no_outliers(x):
     return np.where((x >= x.quantile(0.025)) & (x <= x.quantile(0.975)))[0]

df.apply(lambda x: x[no_outliers(x)].mean(), axis=1)
```